# How can I make a Jasmine test for AngularJS which works with $resource?

Tags: angularjs, testing, resources, jasmine, promise

I've got a service which gets user array from the server:

```
    function getUsers() {
        var UsersResource = $resource('assets/data/users.json', {}, {
            query: {
                method: "GET",
                isArray: true
            }
        });

        var users = UsersResource.query().$promise;
        return users;
    }

    function signIn(loginField, password) {
        return getUsers()
            .then(function(users) {
                for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                    if (users[i].login == loginField && users[i].password == password) {
                        $rootScope.logged = true;
                        $rootScope.user = users[i].login;
                        $location.path('/courses');
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            })
            .catch(function () {
                console.log("Error: Users array wasn't retrieved from the server");
                return false;
            });
    }
```

And now I'm trying to test it this way (yes, it's actually a test for controller, which has a reference to this service):

```
describe('LoginController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('task6'));

    var $rootScope, $controller, LoginService;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _LoginService_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        LoginService = _LoginService_;
    }));

    describe('LoginController.submitLogin', function() {
        it('tests if such user exists', function(done) {
            var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            var controller = $controller('LoginController', {$scope: $scope});
            controller.loginField = 'John';
            controller.password = 'Smith';
            LoginService.signIn(controller.loginField,
                                controller.password)
            .then(function(logged) {
                expect(false).toBe(true);
                done();
            })
            $scope.$digest();
        });
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work: "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL."
And I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. :)

P.S. or it would be even better if I could test controller itself, which works with service:

```
self.submitLoginForm = function() {
        LoginService.signIn(self.loginField, self.password)
            .then(function(logged) {
                if(!logged) {
                    self.loginError = true;
                }
            })
            .catch(console.log.bind(console));
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the http request with [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)